# ImageView меняет размер после вставления BItmap

Tags: android, view, adapter, bitmap, imageview

У меня есть список изображений. Я его отображаю в GridView с помощью адаптера:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Book book = getItem(position);
    ImageView preview;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        preview = new ImageView(mContext);
        int height = Utilities.convertDpToPixels(175, mContext);
        int width = Utilities.convertDpToPixels(175, mContext);
        preview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, height));
        preview.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        preview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    } else {
        preview = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    preview.setId(position);
    Bitmap bitmap = Utilities.loadImageFromStorage(book.getPath(), book.getTitle());
    preview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return preview;
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужны одинаковые ячейки, а после вставления туда Bitmap, они меняют свой размер под размер Bitmap. Как можно зафиксировать размеры View. Изображение чтобы обрезалось по центру. Я думал использовать метод ручного обрезания картинки, но это увеличит процесс загрузки списка.

Comment: Использовать установленный размер imageView вместо wrap_content?

Comment: @ahgpoug а почему wrap_content? у меня же заданы параметры слоя:    
`int height = Utilities.convertDpToPixels(175, mContext);
        int width = Utilities.convertDpToPixels(175, mContext);
        preview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, height));`

Comment: Куда Вы загружаете изображение? В `ImageView`. Честно, не вчитывался в этот код, но, скорее всего, у элемента стоит параметр `wrap_content`. Что мешает заранее задать его размеры?

Comment: Да, про вопрос обрезания изображения по центру - используйте Glide для обработки изображений. В нем можно сразу загрузить изображение в `ImageView` и образать по центру, да вообще как угодно обрезать. + не будет больших утечек памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами разрешаете ImageView подгонять свои размеры под изображение

```
preview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Вместо этого ставьте

```
preview.setScaleType(CENTER_INSIDE или CENTER_CROP);
```